# R Shiny upload error

Tags: r, file, upload, shiny, tabpanel

I am trying to build a web app with R Shiny. In my app i want to have 3 tabPanels. This is my code..

```
tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "500px")),
        tabPanel("name",
                h1("example"),
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.ta == true",
                    tableOutput('values1'),
                    tags$hr(),
                    verbatimTextOutput('textDisplay')
                )
          ),
              tabPanel("Frequency Analysis",
              # h1("example2"),
              # tableOutput('values2'),
               #tags$hr(),)
               ) )
```

I want to upload a file so i use `fileInput('file1', 'Choose a file t/plain', '.txt'))`.
The problem is that if i try to put out the comments in the 3rd tabpanel my file is not uploaded?? i don't understand the reason.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your problem, but this is working for me :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Plot",
           plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "500px")),
  tabPanel("name",
           h1("example"),
           conditionalPanel(condition = "input.ta == true",
                            tableOutput('values1'),
                            tags$hr(),
                            verbatimTextOutput('textDisplay')
           )
  ),
  tabPanel("Frequency Analysis",
            h1("example2"),
           sidebarPanel(fileInput("files", "Choose file")),
          tableOutput('values2'),
           tags$hr())
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```